# How does re-usable boosters by SpaceX return back and land on the deck 'Of Course I still Love You'?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, reuse, booster

The idea was to bring back the rockets/boosters safely and re-use them for next time. How SpaceX was able to achieve this?
Intuitively there have to be multiple sensors recording and computer analysing the position or orientation of the rockets. What else goes into training the system? AI (Reinforcement Learning perhaps or just use of sensors to maintain the orientation?)

How entire system works in accordance with the natural way rockets used to return back on earth previously?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the Falcon 9 know where the landing barge/pad is?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/8779/how-does-the-falcon-9-know-where-the-landing-barge-pad-is)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something of a duplicate, since it has been answered in various forms in other questions like:

- [How will the SpaceX landing barge (ASDS) get to the proper location?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/6590/how-will-the-spacex-landing-barge-asds-get-to-the-proper-location)
- [How does the Falcon 9 first stage land on the moving surface of the barge?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/15229/how-does-the-falcon-9-first-stage-land-on-the-moving-surface-of-the-barge)
- [How does the Falcon 9 know where the landing barge/pad is?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/8779/how-does-the-falcon-9-know-where-the-landing-barge-pad-is)
- [Technologies use by SpaceX to enable landing on a drone ship [duplicate]](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/15195/technologies-use-by-spacex-to-enable-landing-on-a-drone-ship)

In short, they calculate in advance where the barge should be, it knows where it should be the booster knows where it should go, and uses GPS to get there.

This is likely why when they lost an engine on the Starlink-5 mission, they were able to make it to orbit via the 8 other engines, but their position differed sufficient from a normal launch that they could not guide the booster far enough to get back to the barge with the available fuel.